# InDesign: how to move part of child text frame on the next page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a master page with only one text frame with 'Smart Text Reflow' option enabled to add new pages automatically. At the first page i added child text frame into right upper corner of the parent frame and turned on 'Auto-Size' option to 'Height' only.

How to move part of the child frame to the next page automatically?

[image]

Comment: Autoflow and multiple text frames is a tricky thing.

If you want to play with it, you must place your text instead of pasting it.
Hit the Shift key while placing it in order to allow the autoflow of the loaded text.
See https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/threading-text.html#flow_text_manually_or_automatically

Answer (score 1):

Select the *Child Text Frame*, click the red + symbol at the bottom-right. Without releasing the mouse, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space-bar</kbd> and drag to the next page.

Click on an empty area of the page to let the text flow. Set the new text frame size and position.

Comment: Two moments: 1) child frame does not have red + symbol, because for this frame 'Auto-Size (Height)' option is enabled. 2) I want to make inDesign do it automatically, without clicking on the frame.

Comment: @AlxZahar Your comment here highlights exactly why what you were looking for is not possible: the auto-size option means that the frame with always resize to fit its content with no overflow. With no overflow, there is nothing to move to the next page. If you want reflowing to the next page, you have to get rid of the auto-size.